# SQL convert DATETIME TO VARCHAR?

Tags: sql

I am working on a query something require DATE!!

```
DECLARE @YesterDay DATETIME, @Today DATETIME 

SET @YesterDay = DateAdd(DD, DateDiff(DD, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) 
SET @Today = DateAdd(DD, DateDiff(DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
select @YesterDay = convert(varchar, getdate()-1 , 110) 
select @Today = convert(varchar, getdate() , 110) 
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[post_sec_admin_list_user_log]
        @pDateFr = @YesterDay ,
        @pDateTo = @Today,
        @pName = '',
        @pSec = NULL


@DateFr is varchar(50)
@DateT0 is varchar(50)
```

the `@dateFr` and `@dateTo` are both `varchar`..

And I try to execute it, it print the time format as this `2011-06-09 16:15:38.927`

error statement

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Additionally, the `varchar` format I need is `MM-DD-YYYY`

Anyone know where is my error at?

thanks

Comment: Put your error in the question!

Comment: Which RBDMS? I'm guessing SQL Server. I'm also guessing the error occurs within the `post_sec_admin_list_user_log` stored procedure, which you haven't posted the code for.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing:

```
DECLARE @YesterDay DATETIME, @Today DATETIME
SET @YesterDay = DateAdd(DD, DateDiff(DD, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) 
SET @Today = DateAdd(DD, DateDiff(DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
select @YesterDay = convert(varchar, getdate()-1 , 110) 
select @Today = convert(varchar, getdate() , 110)
```

So you declare it as DATETIME, set value with DateDiff then overwrite that value with an varchar representation of a date that is recalculated using different method.

At line 4 and 5 @Yesterday and @Today variables are still DATETIME, because it's declared that way.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment to my answer you need a variable to pass to the procedure.
So the correct fix would be to declare the variables as VARCHAR(50) at the beginning and do the conversion directly.

```
DECLARE @YesterDay VARCHAR(50), @Today VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @YesterDay = convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()) , 110) 
SELECT @Today = convert(varchar(50), getdate() , 110)
```

And then call the procedure the way you did originally.

Comment: Actually you can't use anything other than either variables or static values when passing parameters, so CONVERT(varchar, @Yesterday, 110) needs assigning to a variable first.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that getdate()-1 part is wrong.

Also, you were making `dateadd` and `datediff` why? Try it like this:

```
SET @YesterDay = dateadd(dd, -1, GETDATE()) 
SET @Today = GETDATE() 
select @YesterDay = convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()) , 110) 
select @Today = convert(varchar(50), getdate() , 110)
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[post_sec_admin_list_user_log]
        @pDateFr = @YesterDay ,
        @pDateTo = @Today,
        @pName = '',
        @pSec = NULL
```

Comment: your code is better but the code OP submited will calculate "yesterday" correctly. But that's not what is causing the issue. The problem is Yesterday and Today are defined as DATETIME and he's trying to pass them as varchar.